# How is coherent noise more detrimental than incoherent noise for QEC when QEC is supposed to decohere noise?

Tags: error-correction, noise

It's sometimes mentioned that unitary, coherent, noise can adversely impact the performance of QEC codes compared to purely stochastic Pauli noise. This motivates protocols such as [randomized compiling](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.01098) which tailors noise to stochastic Pauli errors via Pauli twirling. On the other hand, it's a well known property of quantum error correction that repeated syndrome measurements decoheres unitary errors. So how exactly worse are coherent errors for QEC compared to incoherent errors?